# Getting HTML element in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I am struck in a problem, i want a small amount of data from a site, but this data is present in different pages.

Hence i used curl request to call this pages

Problem:

curl request gives my a html page, and finding that small amount of content is difficult with php as,
  It is very simple to move through the HTML Dom with JavaScript(jquery). Can i move with same ease with php in HTML Dom

any help would be appreciated , please provide me link of such site also

I am not asking for all the coding , but just a  library or link will do

if there is any trick it will also do , **a small example like fetching element with ID would be of great help**

Thanks

Comment: I use Simple DOM Parser for this 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: you can use xpath: http://il1.php.net/domxpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) and [DomXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to navigate your HTML tree and search it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHtml); // HTML as string, use loadHTMLFile() to load a file.
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@id='yourTagIdHere']");
if (empty($elements) || $elements->length == 0)
    echo "Not found";
else
{
    // $elements now contains a DOMNodeList of matching elements
    // which you can foreach() through.
}
```